# android that is this parametr?

Tags: android

This is a stupid question, but I really need to understand this.

```
android.media.audiofx.Visualizer

getfft(byte[] fft)
```

That is `byte[] fft`? Is it the array of frequency that fft I need go get?

Comment: If you really need an answer, why don't you spend a few minutes and put some detail/context in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a Fast Fourier Transform.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform

In that method, you pass in an empty array to fill in. The array should be the size returned by `visualizer.getCaptureSize()`.